# column "invited_by_id" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use devise_invitable. But the thing is it will generate a column invited_by_id automatically for us to reference to the parent model. But the problem is invited_by_id is integer, but the parent model id is of type uuid.

Now I wrote a migration to convert id to uuid

```
class ChangeInvitedById < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :employees, :invited_by_id, :uuid, default: 'uuid_generate_v4()'
  end
end
```

But this giving me this error

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "invited_by_id" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING invited_by_id::uuid".
```

I already have a migration which has this `enable_extension 'uuid-ossp'`

Comment: @gutes did you find a solution to your problem I am stuck at exactly the same problem

Comment: I think I have dropped the invited_by_id and then added with the column with uuid type. Try and let me know